# Cordova Geolocation Wrong Coordinates

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, geolocation

I'm writing an application which tracks the current location and draw it with google.maps.Polyline.
The problem is that even stopped, the current location changes. It also happens while walking straight. Like this:

[image]

This is the code:

```
var watchOptions = { timeout: 1000, enableHighAccuracy: false // get the same behaviour with 'true' };

var track = []; // coordinates to draw with Polyline

watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);

changeMarker(myMarker, latLng);

watch.then(
  null,
  function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  },
  function(position) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    // push current position to array
    track.push({ lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude});

var trackPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: track,  // pass coordinates
      strokeColor: "#2980b9",
      geodesic: true,
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    // draw on map
    trackPath.setMap($scope.map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, setting `enableHighAccuracy: false` will use low-accuracy network triangulation, as opposed to `enableHighAccuracy: true` which will engage the GPS hardware. For navigation (e.g. walking) you should always set it to true.

Even then, GPS locations are not exact, there will be some error - how much depends on many factors such as the GPS hardware in your device, any obscuring of the sky (e.g. trees, buildings), and how many satellites have been locked.

To enable high accuracy locations to be delivered frequently, I would recommend settings such as:

```
{
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  maxAge: 0,
  timeout: 30000
}
```

Comment: When using wi-fi, location is more exact than using Cellular Data. Is there a way to prevent wrong coordinates?

Comment: there should be a `position.coords.accuracy` value which indicates the approximate accuracy in metres. For cellular data this value will be much higher, so you can use it to ignore positions that are too inaccurate i.e. `if(position.coords.accuracy > 50) return console.log("Ignoring position as it's too inaccurate")`

Comment: Hey @DaveAlden you answered in the comment line bro , I was using the same config but that was not the problem as I saw your comment and made a treshold for that accuracy and my problem solved. Thanks.